# Sorting Items In A Listbox Numerically

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listboxitems

I'm having trouble sorting items in a listbox numerically. All my filenames that have a "1" are grouped together. Example = (file1, file10, file11, file2, file3, file4, etc)

I have the Sorted option on the listbox set to True but doesn't appear to work correctly.

Here's how I'm currently adding my items.

```
    Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBox1_Path.Text)
    Dim fileInfos() As System.IO.FileInfo            
    fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
    For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fileInfos
        ListBoxUPSFiles.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
    Next
```

I'd like to sort them as file1, file2, file3, file4, etc.

Suggestions on sorting the filenames?

Comment: LBS_SORT sorts alphabetically, thus the order you are seeing.  What order would you like to see?

Comment: I'd like to sort them as file1, file2, file3, file4, etc.

Comment: C++ provides the ability to encode some "item" data using [SetItemData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck636w45.aspx).  The data can be used to sort the list in any fashion.  Do you have similar capability?

Comment: I'm not sure about that for VB, I'll take a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting Listbox Items numerically in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157383/sorting-listbox-items-numerically-in-vb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the listbox sorting and do:

```
For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fileInfos.OrderBy( _
    Function(fi) Integer.Parse(Regex.Match(fi.Name, "\d+").Value))
    ListBoxUPSFiles.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Wish I could give +2 for adding the RegEx