# Listbox Sorting Issue

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listbox

I am having trouble sorting a listbox the way I am expecting it to work even using the sorted = true property. Assuming i have files named as such, when i sort by "Name" in a Windows Folder view (outside of vb) it sorts like so:

```
1180741
1179715
1162371
1141511
1131750
1117362
1104199
1082698
1062921
1043875
991514
970621
963154
952954
948067
917669
904315
899902
892398
882024
```

This is how i need it to be sorted in my list. However, with the sorted = true property, vb.net decides to sort like this:

```
1043875
1062921
1082698
1104199
1117362
1131750
1141511
1162371
1179715
1180741
882024
892398
899902
904315
917669
948067
952954
963154
970621
991514
```

I cannot understand why windows sorts the list correctly but VB does not. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your code is sorting a ListBox which has strings in it (apparently).  As such an alphabetical/text sort is being applied.  9 is always large than 1 or 10 or 11

Comment: Take a look at this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157383/sorting-listbox-items-numerically-in-vb

Answer (score 0):

### [image]

*This example assumes that each object in the listbox is a string representation of an integer, if in the case that it is not, the item will be skipped, you can modify this to handle such a case in another way if you want....
Example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Dim r As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'We simulated a populated listbox
        For I As Integer = 0 To 1000
            Dim n As Integer = r.Next(0, Integer.MaxValue)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(n.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SortListBoxNumbers(ListBox1)
    End Sub
    Sub SortListBoxNumbers(listbox As ListBox)
        Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)
        For Each item As Object In listbox.Items
            Dim n As Integer = 0
            If item.GetType = GetType(String) Then
                If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(item, String), n) Then
                    numbers.Add(n)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        listbox.Items.Clear()
        numbers = SortNumbers(numbers)
        For Each n As Integer In numbers
            listbox.Items.Add(n.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
    Function SortNumbers(numbers As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim result As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim count As Integer = numbers.Count
        Do
            Dim highN As Integer = Integer.MinValue
            For Each n As Integer In numbers
                If n > highN Then highN = n
            Next
            numbers.Remove(highN)
            result.Insert(result.Count, highN)
        Loop Until result.Count = count
        result.Reverse()
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```