# Ordering numbers highest to lowest

Tags: vb.net, sorting

For a highscore page in my game I am taking the 1st to 5th highest values from a text file and then displaying them in a text box but I am having the issue that my code is seeing each digit as a separate number, an example being that 43 will be read as 4 and 3. This means my highsore page never shows a score above 9. The text file is in the rescources if the program and contain a new number on each line.

How do i fix this?

Code Below.

```
'Part 1: Determine Resource File Path based on Debugging mode or Published mode  
Dim ResourceFilePathPrefix As String
If System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached() Then
    'In Debugging mode  
    ResourceFilePathPrefix = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\resources\")
Else
    'In Published mode  
    ResourceFilePathPrefix = Application.StartupPath & "\resources\"
End If

'Part 2: Write the text file
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(ResourceFilePathPrefix & "scores.txt")
Array.Sort(lines)
Array.Reverse(lines)
P1Score.Text = lines(0)
P2Score.Text = lines(1)
P3Score.Text = lines(2)
P4Score.Text = lines(3)
P5Score.Text = lines(4)
```

Comment: Your first mistake is to believe that a list of numbers stored as strings will produce the same result as a list of numbers stored as numbers when sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Listbox Items numerically in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157383/sorting-listbox-items-numerically-in-vb)

Comment: You use `Sort` on text items, so yeah, you get what you ask for. Make it an array of integers instead.

Comment: You can easily do this with LINQ. If you're storing integers then: `Dim numbers = File.ReadAllLines("...").Select(Function(s) Int32.Parse(s))`

Comment: sorry, i couldnt seem to get that to work

Comment: OK Ignore my now deleted comment, I was about to totally overcomplicate things - does the scores.txt file JUST contain scores, or does it include other text such as the scorer's name? Could you let us know what the format of each line it please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the scores into integers before you can sort them numerically otherwise they will be sorted as text (which is how the scores are stored in the file).

```
'Part 2: Write the text file
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(ResourceFilePathPrefix & "scores.txt")

Dim scores As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
For Each line As String in lines
    scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(line))
Next

scores.Sort()
scores.Reverse()

P1Score.Text = scores(0)
P2Score.Text = scores(1)
P3Score.Text = scores(2)
P4Score.Text = scores(3)
P5Score.Text = scores(4)
```

Or using Linq:

```
'Part 2: Write the text file
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(ResourceFilePathPrefix & "scores.txt")
Dim scores = lines.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x)).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x)
P1Score.Text = scores(0)
P2Score.Text = scores(1)
P3Score.Text = scores(2)
P4Score.Text = scores(3)
P5Score.Text = scores(4)
```